# viewstate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

can we store viewstate other than in hidden field in asp.net

Comment: Where did you want to store it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  There are a number of different implementations out there for moving ViewState to Sql Server, for example.  But often, when you want to do this a better option is to make a few smaller changes to your site to reduce the number of postbacks and the amount of information placed in viewstate in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [Moving ViewState to the Session Object and more Wrongheadedness](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheSessionObjectAndMoreWrongheadedness.aspx)